# Why is looking at thinly claded and/or sexually attractive women haram?

Tags: halal-haram, women, modesty

I never understood this. I am a Muslim and respect and enjoy looking at beautiful women (naturally). I don't understand why it is so bad to look at a woman. I feel a new modern Islam should promote women's freedom to dress the way they want, and for men to enjoy them.

I don't see anything wrong if a man watches videos of sexually attractive women. *How could it possibly be haram?* She isn't naked, she isn't doing a sex tape or anything. Simply showing off her fit body in beautiful lingerie. Men watch it, enjoy it, and have fun with it. Some women also watch it and enjoy it.

Can we not accept this as a new part of the modern Islam (women's freedom of clothing)? I don't see myself ever giving up enjoying women. I don't commit adultery, or drink, or smoke because I truly see a problem there. But freedom of dress for women and freedom for men to enjoy women, there is *zero* harm in that. I have nothing against women wearing bikinis (showing off how hard they worked on their bodies) rather than woman in burqa. And I don't have a problem with a woman dancing in front of men for their entertainment. What is wrong with that?

Things have to make sense in a religion and this clearly does not. Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the video link is not appropriate.

Comment: Umm the video link is to make a point... of harmless entertainment?

Comment: True, but there's no need to demonstrate it; the point gets across. anyway. Cost/benefit balance is important. The inappropriateness of showing it far outweighs any benefit.

Comment: It is  NOT harmless. It is harmful and shameless promotion of promiscuity and obscenity.

Comment: Please do not restore the removed link! Otherwise you'll get banned and your question removed! Respect site policies!

Comment: An inappropriate (video) link cannot deem a question as off-topic, @Najeeb.

Comment: ^Exactly... they are just scared of the woman because she is beautiful or something...

Comment: @user8189, no one is scared but it is haram to look at thinly clothed women in Islam for the great possibility of lustful look. Women are not objects of pleasure that you can randomly watch and enjoy! You should correct your ill-thinking!

Comment: people allege [women are hated in islam](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16833/why-are-women-hated-in-islam-why-are-they-not-free-to-wear-act-and-behave-the) since they are advised to cover themselves up in proper clothes. But in fact, instigating women to wear scanty clothes is a conspiracy to use women as object of pleasure, and this question and the video in link in it gives the proof.

Comment: Just saying ..... to you it seems that wearing transparent clothes is harmless and entertaining and men should be blamed for their actions.... someone who goes more extreme than you can ask if women want to, they should be naked and they should be given a choice to be naked or not. Your lustful desires are what should be changed Islam cannot change because of your desires

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid what you wrote shows that you're trying to alter Islam to fit to your carnal desires.

Human sexuality in Islam is not for fun and pleasure but it has a sacred function that is undermined by a hedonistic view of human sexuality. 
Sexuality with all its pleasures and attractions, is to serve a noble purpose: long term family commitment for extending the vital human reproduction process and also enabling partners to fulfill their lofty Islamic responsibilities through collective family life i.e. upbringing of children, providing sustenance, housekeeping, educating themselves etc.

But in free and irresponsible sexual exchange and pleasure-seeking, non of these sacred functions are fulfilled and you finally get a morally bankrupt and divided society with subverted families where everyone is following his/her egoistic/carnal desires without regard to greater good. Just looking at the high level of sexual crimes and decline of family ties in many western societies reveals the determinant consequences of sexual freedom.

Such a society also turns into a very easy prey to corrupt power elite who seek subjugation of nations. In fact if you study power structure in the West you might be surprised that the same power elite who are reigning supreme over western societies (i.e. usurious banks and greedy corporations) also own western corporate media and entertainment industry as main sources of promoting hedonistic and promiscuous lifestyle in western societies.

Comment: So why don't we learn to better ourselves, so that women can freely dress what they want and men and women both learn to still support the other views that Islam promotes? Why is that not possible? Why do we have to say women are punished because we humans can't control ourselves? Men aren't punished. Why are women restrictred from wearing what they want, drivign where they want (Saudi)? Why are women the target?

Comment: Both men and women according to Islam have responsibility toward moral well-being of the society: men's part is to respect women and refuse to cast lustful looks at them (lowering their gazes), women's part is to refuse to show off their sexual beauty to random men on the street. They should be only revealed to their husbands and partially to their very close family members.

Comment: Ok I get it... is there any real reason behind this other than God's commandment? As in, what if there is a way for men to still respect women while giving them their freedom to dress? Is it really impossible to do this?

Comment: @user8189, exposing one's body invites lustful looks. And you already admit that you adore them for their sex not for their humanity. And that is considered sin!

Comment: I think I see where you guys are getting at, but it just doesnt make sense that women don't have the freedom to dress. Its the only part of Islam that makes no sense to me. I have no problem watching women in bikinis and if my Mom or daughter chose to wear what they want, I don't mind. It's their choice! Men choose whatever they want, why can't women do so too!!! And if men want to enjoy the view, why can't they?!? I feel this change is critical for Islam to win in this day in age. The freedom of women must be upheld.

Comment: You make no sense! If you embrace Islam after studying and accepting the reasons for the belief and practices, you have actually accepted to regulate your deeds according to Islamic principles, and that *absolute* freedom of choice is not right, just as freedom for criminal behavior is not right. The difference is that in Islam there are many other criminal acts that are normal and permissible according to secular standards, and that includes arbitrary and unregulated sensual pleasures and carnal desires, avoidance of which is a fundamental and integral part of Islam and being a good muslim!

Comment: @infatuated: Men can be regarded as lustful too when they show their upper body to women at the beach. It's just the obligation to the individual him/herself not to commit into zina afterwards. May Allah have mercy on the righteous men and women.

Answer (score 2):

Man the question you asked might just start a super fest and every brother or sister is going to start shooting answers to your question from everywhere.

In simple sense, Islam as a religion is a matter of simplicity and submission to Allah and how he has asked to go about most of our lives and that is to worship him as the one true god.

Having said this and today's world, how amazing the skyscrapers are, this city has this amazing symbol and high tech fast trains and the list goes on. But a devout Muslim would tell you wait stop, why are you spending so much money on all of this infrastructure when you can see people who can't avail health care or simply get jobs to support their livelihood. But modern sense will tell you we need economic growth and investments so we need to develop at least basic infrastructure like tall and long bridges.

About your pleasures, I will directly say one thing and try my best not to put you to shame or belittle you. And that answer would be you will have to understand yourself and may Allah show you the way that one thing always leads to another and it goes on.

So some small video clip in youtube will go a long way in how your mind consciously and unconsciously responds to it. This part you will have to find yourself like i said either you seek the truth or may Allah show you the way himself.

Answer (score 1):

Islam provides us the best and most effective solutions while trying to convince others about the truth.

> Invite to the way of your Lord with wisdom and good instruction, and argue with them in a way that is best. Indeed, your Lord is most knowing of who has strayed from His way, and He is most knowing of who is [rightly] guided. [[Qur'an: 16:125]](http://quran.com/16/125)

This principle of instructing others with wisdom is amply demonstrated in the hadith that follows. See how the Messenger of Allah (SAWS) answered in the best and most effective way that made the young lad see sense.

> A young man of the Quraish came to the Prophet one day and said: "O Prophet! Give me permission to commit adultery." Some of the Companions who were present, seeing this request as being against Islamic morals, told him to be quiet and scolded the young man. Prophet Muhammad was very calm and told the young man "Come over here and sit down." Then he turned to him and started to talk with him. "Tell me, would you like for another to commit adultery with your mother?" The young man said "O Prophet of Allah, I would never desire such a thing." The Prophet said: "No one would want such a thing for their mother." He continued, and said: "Would you want someone to commit adultery with your daughter?" The young man said "O Prophet of Allah, I would not." The Prophet said: "No one would want for their daughter to commit adultery." Then he went on to ask if the young man would approve of his sister, paternal aunt or maternal aunt committing adultery. Each time, the young man answered: "No, I would not want that." When he saw that the youth had understood his error the Prophet put his hand on the young man's shoulder and said "My Lord, forgive him his sin, clean his heart and protect him from committing sins." The young man, according to his own words, did not allow the emotion of lust to enter his heart again. [Ahmad b. Hanbal, Musnad, Beirut, IV, 256-257]

Attraction towards women is natural for any man, and a Muslim too is no exception. However, before trying to justify fahisha (indecency) to yourself and to others, bear this hadith in mind and ask yourself: Would you like it if your mother and sister and aunts all dressed up that way and every inch of their bodies was then admired by men? Would you like the ladies of your household to be ogled at?

Answer that to yourself, and you will get your answer. Islam is natural and only promotes that which is natural. No man would like that the women of his household were ogled at, and Islam formalizes this formal fitrah or nature of man. Do unto others as you would have others do unto you.

Comment: See I am not saying ALL women should do this behavior. What I am saying is that women should have the CHOICE for themselves. What is wrong with that? AND men should learn to keep their distance and respect them despite what they wear. That's all I'm saying. KEEP THE FREEDOM. Responses?

Comment: Are women important only because they're the relative of a man?

Answer (score 0):

As said before all you're trying to do is mend Islam into your version so it can accommodate your harraam actions! I will not tell you what the others told you above, since they have done justice, alhamdulillah.

They already have the choice! They can wear a bikini in a place where there are women only or in front of their husbands, they are also allowed to dress for their husbands.

No man will never stop looking at a women wearing minimal clothing. It's natural and it can't stop! For Muslim however, we must lower our gaze.

Everything is wrong with that you just said.

Answer (score 0):

Choices come with consequences, brother...both for men, women and society in general. Allah has given us a conscience to tell us right from wrong and a brain that tells us how to behave in a responsible way and contribute to society and the concept of accountability. These are the values that Allah teaches us in the Quran using prophets as role models. 
Heaven is for those who are patient in this world and practice taqwa ie piety...the path to Jannah is very hard and requires a lot of control and patience but the reward is enormous and worth the sacrificing and self control. May Allah help us all achieve our goals here and in the hereafter.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You know why? The ultimate reason? This is because to test your ability to sacrifice freedom for a very short 70 to 90 years in exchange for jannah where you can do anything. This is the price Allah has put up for us in this short game. Why men and women are ordered different clothing you ask?  If both genders had similar freedom in terms of clothing, that would not be much of a challenge, eh? And also, men are a machine that can go on and on with several woman to produce babies infinitely with their primal instincts. If women do not put on veil, while it may not cause fitnah (temptation) for you and others, there will be many that it will, and others who will even act upon it. Finally, I also think it may cause desensitization on the men's part seeing to much skin and would be less inclined to reproduce with women. Men have 10 times more testosterone in their body. No matter how much you tell some men not to gaze at unveiled sister, some will always be there. For women's security and privacy, it is the command of Allah to sisters to veil themselves.